# Why are my socket.io events coming through in chunks?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, real-time, edge.js

I'm trying to build a real-time game and streaming updates via node.js and sockets.io to the client.

I'm using latest Chrome browser, but I've tried in FF as well.

All the server-side code is logging to the console correctly, so I know the timing is good there, but on the client, it seems the messages are arriving in "chunks" rather than streaming.

Server:

```
var util = require("util");
var io = require("socket.io");
var socket = io.listen(8000);

init () {
    socket.sockets.on("connection", onSocketConnection);
};

function onSocketConnection(client) {
    util.log("New player has connected: " + client.id);

    client.on("disconnect", onClientDisconnect);
    client.on("getMatchupUpdates", onUpdateMatchup);
};

/* I'm calling an edge.js function to perform game stuff with a callback 
to a js function 'onUpdateTime' to update a game clock on the client browser*/

function onUpdateTime(data)
{
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit("update time", data);
}
```

The console.log produces expected output at 500ms:

```
{ gameID: 77, secondsRemaining: 10 }
{ gameID: 77, secondsRemaining: 10 }
{ gameID: 77, secondsRemaining: 9 }
{ gameID: 77, secondsRemaining: 9 }
{ gameID: 77, secondsRemaining: 8 }
....
```

So I know the callback is getting back to the node.js server, but then calling to client:

```
function onUpdateTime(data) {
    console.log("received Time Update: ");
    console.log(data);
    $('#clockTimer').text(data.secondsRemaining);
}
```

I get the messages in "chunks". The data is coming thru in the correct format, but the websockets seem to be falling back to polling:

```
http://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1435865813074-17&sid=WaNEY1UQUdkx6RLfAAAA
```

The Console logs correctly, but again, in chunks rather than a stream...

```
> HTML1.html:802 Object {gameID: 77, secondsRemaining: 7}
> HTML1.html:802 received Time Update:  
> HTML1.html:803 Object {gameID: 77, secondsRemaining: 7} 
> HTML1.html:802 received Time Update:  
> HTML1.html:803 Object {gameID: 77, secondsRemaining: 6}
> HTML1.html:802 received Time Update:  
> HTML1.html:803 Object {gameID: 77, secondsRemaining: 6}
```

Any advice? Thoughts? Additional Needs?

**UPDATE: **
I've added the edge call here:

```
//set up update callback
var payload = {
matchupID: data.id,
updateTime: function (input, callback) {
    callback(null, onUpdateTime(input));
},
updateScore: function (input, callback) {
    callback(null, console.log(input));
},
updateGameBoard: function (input, callback) {
    callback(null, console.log(input));
}
};

GetUpdates(payload, function (error, result) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(result);
});
```

it's worth noting I also changed to code to emit the message in the callback:

```
//set up update callback
var payload = {
    matchupID: data.id,
    updateTime: function (input, callback) {
        callback(null, socket.emit("update time", input));
    },
    updateScore: function (input, callback) {
        callback(null, console.log(input));
    },
    updateGameBoard: function (input, callback) {
        callback(null, console.log(input));
    }
};
```

and ended up with a Stack Overflow Exception...

Comment: FWIW: I tested a dummy loop that just emitted messages to the client at 500ms via socket and it worked fine, so I'm not sure where the holdup is. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to delete this question, but I'll admit I've used a workaround by creating a secondary 'GetTime' hook using edge into the C# dll.

On the nodejs side, I just set an interval and call that GetTime hook every 500ms and things seem to be working now.

It's definitely worth more exploration, but I'm moving on for now.

Answer (score 0):

I would check how many concurrent requests the browser is making out to the server that serves the long polls. You may be bumping into the concurrent connection limit. Once that limit is exceeded, subsequent requests are queued on the client. In case of long polling, the observable effect is often the one you described: long polls take a long time to complete and once they do, you get a batch of messages at once.

Bottom line is I don't think this is related to your use of edge.js, since the callbacks from C# appear timely.

Comment: On a hunch, I updated the edge call to directly call the socket.emitter as a callback (see updated code above) and got a stack overflow exception.